# Can't run asp.net app on os x with dnx . kestrel

Tags: asp.net, mono, visual-studio-code

I followed [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5) to install tools to run asp.net on os x.
I scaffolded the asp.net web application successfully, but and run all the commands the application isn't running.

```
macbook$ cd '/Users/macbook/Documents/Leisure/asp/webapp' ; /Users/macbook/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta6/bin/dnx . kestrel
info    : [Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices] User profile is available. Using '/Users/macbook/.local/share/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Started
```

Everything seems fine, but when I go to localhost:5000 I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, even though kestrel is set at this url.

What's not right? how do I get my asp.net app working?

Comment: If you followed that tutorial is I did when they published it, then kestrel is on port 5001, so: http://localhost:5001

Comment: In hosting.init it's 5000 @RobertN

Comment: Resolved by placing setting server.urls=http://127.0.0.1:5000 and accessing 127.0.0.1:5000 and not localhost:5000

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer. It helps other users who may have the same  problem.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by placing setting server.urls=127.0.0.1:5000 and accessing 127.0.0.1:5000 and not localhost:5000, there was probably a conflict with Apache config